# Gitlab project visibility forced to public in order to download packages

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I would like to keep the visibility level of my gitlab project to "internal" for security reasons.
But if I have to download the packages of the project from project's "packages and registries" using curl , I have to change the visibility level to public. It works only then!

I tried curl command with deploy token and access token  which has full read and write access to package registry, but still doesnt work.

Looking for ways to make this work without compromising visibility level.

I am using version 14.6.0 enterprise edition of gitlab.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
@Arty-chan - The command that am using is: curl -H "ci_token:****"  https://mydomaindotcom/api/v4/projects/#/packages/maven/id/project-name/version-number/application.jar --output application.jar

output when the visibility is public vs internal is:
[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you need the `api` scope for access token to download from package registry. `read_registry` only grants access to container registry images.

Comment: all scopes checked (api, read_api, read_repository, write_repository, read_registry, write_registry), but unless i make the project visibility to public I am not able to download from package registry

Comment: that sounds like a bug, but can you provide (sanitized) copies of your command and the response you get?

Comment: @Arty-chan - I edited my question section. I could not add the details here... When the visibility is not public it downloads an empty file...